# How to find out what IP belongs to what POD in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have following scenario:

- there is running POD with web services (POD A)
- other PODs calls this web services from POD A
- on POD A I would like to find out from incoming IP to what POD name this IP belongs to

I tried to watch via HTTP kubernetes API to see changes to all PODs (when IP is assigned to particular POD). It works pretty well in most cases but in some cases the API server is pushing POD IP change after first request arrives to POD A. It seems there is some delays based on cluster load - e.g. on top of every hour we start a lot of jobs and in short time period the API watcher is slightly delayed by couple of seconds:

- request arrives from IP x.y.z (POD is in pending / running state)
- I checked k8s API - there is not yet any POD with IP x.y.z
- in few seconds if I retry the POD with IP x.y.z it is there

I would like to have reliable way to map IP to POD Name upon first request.

We use CoreDNS.

Comment: Are you able to use k8s sdk/pkgs from within Pod A to query API server? You can get Pod IP from a `get pods` function and map the source IP of incoming requests to Pods that way.

Comment: @Serge I didn't try SDK, but used http (java implementation) to access the api server from Pod A. I believe the SDK is using the api server via http as well, so do not expect to see different behaviour.

Comment: Can you share more information about your cluster? What's the version? Do you have multiple master nodes? Do you have etcd configured with more than a 1 replica (3,5)?

Comment: Pods are ephemeral so it is guaranteed that your mapping of IP to Port will be erroneous at some point. Can you explain your use case further? This certainly seems like a misuse of Kubernetes capabilities.

Comment: @serge based on the pod label / name I want to return data / configuration which is intended only for this particular pod name. We have central repository with configuration and want to restrict access to configuration.

Comment: k8s 1.18, multi-master, multiple etcd replicas, running in IBM Cloud

Comment: Authn/Authz of applications is usually done through things like service accounts and RBAC (external to K8s). Controlling access based on Pod name is not only insecure, its unreliable and its far from canon. Are there other approaches you could consider for your use case?

Comment: You might want to look at StatefulSets + Headless Services

Comment: @PavelMarek as pointed by your comment that you need to send the data to the pod basing specifically on it's label/name, you should look into StatefulSets + Headless Services as pointed by Serge.  You can read more about it here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/. Please tell if this solution would fit your needs.